# error populating dropdown list based on another dropdown list ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdown lists and the second is populated based on the selected value of the first. This is how i had my second dropdown list populated but it wasn't filling based on the selected item in the first which lead me to change how i am filling it.

Before:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="RootDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="FirstChild" DataTextField="DisplayName" DataValueField="ID"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="FirstChild" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT e.DisplayName,  e.ID , e.GUID
FROM SomeTable e
INNER JOIN TabletoTableMap em
ON e.ID = em.OtherTableID
WHERE em.SomeTableID = 9"+ ></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

After:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="RootDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="FirstChild" DataTextField="DisplayName" DataValueField="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Child"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Child Method:

```
protected void Child(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String strConnection = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ALE;Integrated Security=True";
        int RootID = Convert.ToInt32(CourseDropDown.SelectedValue);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConnection);
        con.Open();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT e.DisplayName,  e.ID , e.GUID FROM SomeTable e INNER JOIN TabletoTableMap em ON e.ID = em.OtherTableID WHERE em.SomeTableID="+RootID, con);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        RootElementDropDown.DataSourceID = "FirstChild";
        RootElementDropDown.DataTextField = "DisplayName";
        RootElementDropDown.DataValueField = "ID";
        RootElementDropDown.DataBind();
    }
```

Error:

```
The DataSourceID of 'RootDropDown' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID 'FirstChild' could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Set

```
DataMember as what you want
```

Comment: what part do you mean?

Comment: you already set DataValuefield id .. when selectedindexchanged of first dropdownlist add a method to fill your second dropdownlist as per selection of first before that set a datamember property so that you will get idea of which item is selected and what you want to fill